# Create Azure extensionProperties for an application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-cli

I have a multitenant application in Azure Active directory. We use it for sso (so our customers can log in in our application using their azure ad credentials).

We want to add more information to the user profile. We want to read the value of a property for every user from Azure AD (so the admin can set this property for every user in azure ad).

Lets say this property is "hair_color". This property does not exists in Azure User Object. According to the Azure documentation, I can create an extension (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-directoryextensions-web/) using:

`POST https://graph.windows.net/mydomain.com/applications/my_app_id/extensionProperties?api-version=1.21-preview { “name”: “hair_color”, “dataType”: “String”, “targetObjects”: [“User”] }`

But I'm having problems to create this extension:

- I need a Access-Token to perform this request. So I need to log in with my admin credentials and get this accessToken. Right now my app does not have admin permissions. And I don't like to change the permissions of my app to add a simple extension. Also cause this is an operation that I'm just going to perform once.
- I cannot find any tool to do it. I tried to add the extension using the portal, azure-cli and the graph explorer (https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/ - here I can see my extensions, but I cannot do a POST to create an extension).

Is there a tool to create an extensionProperties for my app? Or at least an easy way to do this. Ideally, I would like to add the extensionProperty leaving my actual application configuration (keeping the permissions and everything else).

PS: Also, I'm not sure about:

- Will this extension appear in Graph API?
- will the Admin be able to change this property from the web browser? or will they need to change it synchronising their local azure ad?

Comment: you can use delegate permission to your app so only user with admin right can do this modification.

Answer (score 0):

At least to partially answer your questions:

After you create the extension for your app, and an admin from another tenant consents to your app, the attribute gets added to their tenant as well. Then if any e.g. user is retrieved from Graph API, and a value has been registered for that property on that user, the extension property will be there.

Comment: What do you mean wit "an admin from another tenant consents to your app"? Do they need to accept it?? I was expecting it to be automatic. So the attribute appears but is empty if the admin does not set a value in Azure ad.

Comment: When the admin signs up for your app, they must consent to the permissions requested by your app. This occurs when they first try to sign in. If they choose to accept the permissions your app requires, they have consented it. This is how multi-tenant apps work in Azure AD.

Comment: So, If instead of a admin, a normal user of another tenant signs up for my app. Then they consent the permissions requested by my app (it does not require any admin permission). Will the property appear?

Comment: A normal user can't sign up for a multi-tenant app. An admin must sign up first, then the normal users can sign in to the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask the admin of the 3rd party tenant to approve use of your app in their tenant via the consent URL with the &prompt=admin_consent querystring parameter, it will accept consent for all users in the AAD so that individual users will never need to consent. Just provide this link to the customer admin.
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_APP_GUID&prompt=admin_consent

With respect to: "So the attribute appears but is empty if the admin does not set a value in Azure AD"
Yes, correct. The extension attribute cannot be set manually by the AAD admin - it can only be set by your app. Your app essentially owns that attribute data and is the only client that can read/write to it. Therefore, at sign on time to your app, where they have no hair colour attribute (for example), you should ask them for it.